# Working out recursive functions

Tags: functions, recursion

I know that a  function is defined recursively when it calls itself to progressively converge on a solution based on an initial
condition. For example if we consider the function defined by
$$Sq(1) = 1$$
$$Sq(n) = Sq(n-1) + 2*n - 1 \quad \text{ for } n > 1$$

The part I am struggling with is working out what $Sq(2)$ and $Sq(3)$ would be (and so on)?

Comment: So, are you trying to find a closed form for sq$(n)$ ?

Comment: I'm trying to work out Sq(2) and Sq(3) to appreciate how this function works.

Comment: Hint: Pile up the differences into a sum and get a closed form. I'm writing the answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out what $Sq(3)$ is, we need to first find out what $Sq(2)$ is, and to find out what $Sq(2)$ is, we first need to find out what $Sq(1)$ is. This is the nature of the recursive definition. Luckily, we already know what $Sq(1)$ is. So

$$Sq(3) = Sq(2) + 2*3 - 1$$
$$Sq(2) = Sq(1) + 2*2 - 1$$
and
$$Sq(1) = 1.$$

Now we plug this value back into $Sq(2)$ and find

$$Sq(2) = 1 + 4 - 1 = 4$$
$$Sq(3) = 4 + 6 - 1 = 9.$$

Comment: That gives only a few values, not the closed form.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Correct, but as far as I understand, this is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Read the question. He wrote "and so on".

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Read the comment. No need to be hostile. If you don't like the answer, you can always downvote it.

Comment: I am looking for Sq(2) and Sq(3) specifically, but I presume a pattern will follow.

Comment: Aha, sorry, I wasn't trying to be hostile. Sorry if it sounded like it.

Comment: We're all friends here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$sq(n)=n^2$$

satisfies the conditions, since

$$n^2=(n-1)^2+2n-1$$

and

$$1^2=1$$

To prove that this is the only possible solution, we can use induction. Assume $sq(n-1)=(n-1)^2$. Then we get:

$$sq(n)=(n-1)^2+2n-1=n^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm denoting sq$(n)$ by $f(n)$. The given recurrence is,

$$f(n)-f(n-1)=2n-1~\forall~n\gt 1~\land~f(1)=1$$

Now, note that the difference between $f(n)$ and $f(n-1)$ is a function in $n$ which is $2n-1$. So, we can make a closed form by "piling up the differences" as,

$$f(n)=c_1+\sum_{i=1}^n (2n-1)~,~\textrm{where }c_1\textrm{ is some constant.}$$

The sum is easy to evaluate and you'll get,

$$f(n)=c_1+n(n+1)-n=c_1+n^2$$

Use the initial value given, $f(1)=1$ to conclude that $c_1=0$. Hence,

$$f(n)=n^2$$